# Using a replicated DB of MySQL in a project

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring

We are working on a new web application with spring MVC.
We already have a Legacy application that runs with a MySQL DB.

1) Is it possible that our new application will use as a dataSource a replicated db of the legacy application? (of course we will have all the entities defined in the new project).

2) Is it possible to add a 2nd data source to the new project that all the new project persistence needs will be executed on it?

3) Is it possible to index the replicated MySQL database that will be used on our new project? (we would like to index the replicated Mysql db differently than the master DB)

4) Is it possible to create triggers specifically on the replicated db and not on the master db?

Comment: Why would you like different indexes and triggers?

Comment: I would like to execute different queries on the replicated db. these queries might be slow unless i index the replicated DB. bear in mind i dont want to index the master DB. as for the Triggers, I have some heavy triggers that i would like to run on the replicated db and not the main db (I dont want to impact the performance of the main db, while the new project may be slow)

Comment: Regarding #1 and #2, is your intention to read objects from data source 1 and then write them to data source 2?  Are you using JPA?

Comment: John R - Yes exactly, that's what i intend on doing, and yes i am using spring with jpa.